# Regex To Find All Special Characters(js)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

Calling all regex gurus. I am trying to the following regex pattern `/(([^a-zA-z0-9-_.])|(^)|([)|(]))/gm` to remove special characters from file names but am a bit confused about why it is not catching
all special characters not included in the first match group. I added the second match group to catch some characters that it was not matching with, but am worried about others that it may not be catching.

Comment: [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Comment: I didn't even notice I made the second z lower case. Thanks!